# how to remove index.php?route= in url using htacess

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

i am facing problems in ingratiating payment gateway cc avenue.  i need to change the url without special charters

my httaccess file is

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]

RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

can any one can help me

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: main problem is i installed the ccavenue gateway in site. but cc avenue is not accepting my url because it contains special charters

Comment: What exactly are those special character URLs. Can you provide some examples?

Comment: How are these characters getting into your URLs?

Comment: i am using opencart for my store. opencart have index.php?route= in all urls now i want to remove special charters

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?_route_=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: main problem is i installed the ccavenue gateway in site. but cc avenue is not accepting my url because it contains special charters

Answer (score 0):

@Jon Lin

Thanks your answer. its working form like this;

```html
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?_route_=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitenamehere.net/$1 [R,L]
```